# write a ruby bit-struct to a socket

Tags: ruby, sockets

I've written a bit-struct in Ruby:

```
class UnitHeader < BitStruct
    default_options :endian => :little
    unsigned :len,          16,  "Length including header and all payload messages"
    unsigned :msgCount,     8,   "Number of messages in payload"
    unsigned :group,        8,   "group the payload messages relate to"
    unsigned :seqNumStart,  32,  "Sequence number of the first payload message"
end
```

I'd like to write this to a socket:

```
uh = UnitHeader.new
...

s = TCPSocket.new("127.0.0.1", 3000)
s.write(uh)
```

The s.write call doesn't seem to write any data.  I've been unable to find anything on this issue in [the documentation](http://bit-struct.rubyforge.org/), is there a ruby operator or similar for this purpose?

Comment: Why not put it in JSON?

Comment: it's binary data and has to be in little endian format

Comment: Next time, please try to properly describe your problem. "Doesn't work" does not aid anyone in trying to help. You should describe what you've been doing, what you are expecting and the unexpected result you are encountering. For this question, it seems like you actually had a problem receiving the data, which wasn't clear from the question at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've presented should work properly. Your problem is probably located elsewhere. Here's how you can debug it to be sure:

1. Create a UnitHeader and set the appropriate values.
2. Using netcat, create a listener socket to test with, and dump the received data to a file: `nc -l 1234 > output`, where 1234 is the port to listen on.
3. Run your code (be sure to **flush or close** your socket)
4. Use `hexdump output` to look at the result, and compare it to your expected result

Comment: upvote requires 15 reputation, but will do so when I get enough!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps someone...

```
# send side of socket
socket.write("#{uh}")

# recv side of socket
uhdata = socket.read(8).unpack("vcAV")
uh     = UnitHeader.new(:len => uhdata[0], :msgCount => uhdata[1], :group=> uhdata[2], :seqNumStart => uhdata[3])
```